# LibGDX can load skin on Desktop but not on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

This code works fine on Desktop, but when I run it on my android phone I get an error.
The Code:

```
public class MainClass extends ApplicationAdapter {

private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;

@Override
public void create () {
    skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    stage=new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

    final Label label=new Label("This is a label",skin,"default");
    label.setPosition(250,0);
    label.setWidth(300);
    label.setHeight(50);

    stage.addActor(label);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
}
```

}

The Error:

```
07-15 03:53:11.298 30926-30956/com.test.skintest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 14997
                                                               Process: com.test.skintest, PID: 30926
                                                               com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
                                                                   at com.test.skintest.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:22)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290)
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
                                                                Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:694)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74) 
                                                                   at com.test.skintest.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:22) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239) 
                                                                Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: uiskin.json
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74) 
                                                                   at com.test.skintest.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:22) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239) 
                                                                Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: uiskin.json (Internal)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74) 
                                                                   at com.test.skintest.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:22) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239) 
                                                                Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: uiskin.json
                                                                   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
                                                                   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:334)
                                                                   at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:308)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74) 
                                                                   at com.test.skintest.MainClass.create(MainClass.java:22) 
                                                                   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:290) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511) 
                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

I know that the error is created because the phone cannot find uiskin.json but i dont understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdx.files.internal` points to `assets` directory, so your file should be `assets/uiskin.json`. This is different from desktop where the path is relative to the root or working directory.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Comment: I moved this file: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json to assets but i still get the same error

Comment: Are you using old directory structure or new one with gradle?
It should be:
`<projectdir>/assets/uiskin.json` for old one and with new structure `<projectdir>/<module>/src/main/assets/uiskin.json`

Comment: i am using the old directory structure